# Duplicate array dimension with numpy (without np.repeat)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to duplicate a numpy array dimension, but in a way that the sum of the original and the duplicated dimension array are still the same. For instance consider a `n x m` shape array (`a`) which I'd like to convert to a `n x n x m` (`b`) array, so that `a[i,j] == b[i,i,j]`. Unfortunately `np.repeat` and `np.resize` are not suitable for this job. Is there another numpy function I could use or is this possible with some creative indexing?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.shape
(3,)
# This is not what I want...
>>> np.resize(a, (3, 3))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

In the above example, I would like to get this result:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 1d to 2d array, you can use the `np.diagflat` method, which *Create a two-dimensional array with the flattened input as a diagonal*:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])

np.diagflat(a)
#array([[1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 2, 0],
#       [0, 0, 3]])
```

More generally, you can create a zeros array and assign values in place with *advanced indexing*:

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

result = np.zeros((a.shape[0],) + a.shape)
idx = np.arange(a.shape[0])
result[idx, idx, :] = a

result
#array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

#       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 4.,  5.,  6.]]])
```

Comment: `np.diagflat(a)` doesn't work correctly. `a.shape = (2, 3)` turns into `np.diagflat(a).shape = (6, 6)`, but I need a shape of `(2, 2, 3)`.

Comment: `np.diagflat` only works if you have 1d array and want to convert it to 2d array with 1d as diagonal, for a 2d array, you'll have to use the second more general solution.